# Command works in bash shell but not alias

Tags: bash, alias

I am running a command as such:

`submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2'`

This command works. However, when I set it as an alias:

`alias foo='submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2''`

it fails with the error:

`bash: alias: -N2: not found`

However, this alias works just fine:

`alias foo='submit -n 72 -x '-N2''`

So there is something specifically about the --mail-type=END snippet that causes problems.

EDIT: Changed alias='... to alias foo='...

Comment: In short: quotes don't nest. The second `'` ends the quoting, so there's an unquoted space between the `END` and `-N2`. The final two quotes quote an empty string, which gets concatenated to the `-N2`, so they don't do anything.

Comment: That's not a valid alias declaration.  Do you actually have something like `alias foo='submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2''` or are you in actual fact attempting to assign this string to a variable named `alias`?

Comment: Yes, I realize now that I typed it wrong in the post but in real life it's `alias foo='submit -n 72 -x '-N2''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoting is off. Instead try using `""` to contain `''` (though `""` interpolates `$variables`, which you may or may not want)

```
alias="submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2'"
```

Or use the `'\''` trick to "end the current single quote, insert a literal quote, restart the current single quote". That is, any inner `'` is replaced with `'\''`

```
alias='submit -n 72 -x '\''--mail-type=END -N2'\'''
```

Here's how I verified whether the quoting produced a single unbroken string and not two words like yours does:

```
# not ok, two distinct words
$ perl -E 'say for @ARGV' 'submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2''
submit -n 72 -x --mail-type=END
-N2

# ok, a single string
$ perl -E 'say for @ARGV' 'submit -n 72 -x '-N2''                
submit -n 72 -x -N2
$ 

# ok, single quotes within doubles
$ perl -E 'say for @ARGV' "submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2'"
submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2'

# ok, '\'' trick
$ perl -E 'say for @ARGV' 'submit -n 72 -x '\''--mail-type=END -N2'\'''
submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2'
$
```

As for `foo='submit -n 72 -x '-N2''`, that is *not* nested; quotes on unix *do not* nest, this is why shells have `$(cmd ... $(cmd ...))` instead of trying to figure out how to nest that using only backticks. `foo='submit -n 72 -x '-N2''` is a more verbose and complicated way to say `foo='submit -n 72 -x '-N2` or even more simply `foo='submit -n 72 -x -N2'`.

Comment: This works! But I don't understand why `alias foo='submit -n 72 -x '-N2''` works also as I mentioned? It also has nested single quotes.

Comment: They are not actually nested, they are adjacent. `submit -n 72 -x` (space) is quoted, and followed by an unquoted `N2`, which is followed by a quoted empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest quotes.  A simple workaround is to use different quotes:

```
alias foo='submit -n 72 -x "--mail-type=END -N2"'
```

A much better workaround is to not use an alias.  Use a function instead.

```
foo () {
    submit -n 72 -x '--mail-type=END -N2' "$@"
}
```